# MySQL Tree Structure of Menu

Tags: mysql

I have created a MySQL database table where I want to show the menu structure based on their parent. The table is as under;

### menu

```
id     menuname                     parentid
-----------------------------------------------
1      dashboard                         0
2      Content                           0
3      Home Page Content                 2
4      Banners                           2
5      Settings                          0
6      Block Content                     3
7      Site Content                      3
```

So that the menu structure will look like:

```
>dashboard
>Content
-->Home Page Content
  -->Block Content
  -->Site Content
-->Banners
>Settings
```

I have written my query as below which produce duplicate rows and not as per the above expectation.

```
SELECT node.id, node.name 
FROM menu AS node, menu AS parent WHERE node.parentid = parent.parentid
```

Comment: This exact output is something which should be handled in your presentation layer, rather than in MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! I do not want the indentation in MySQL. can you provide me the raw query for this?

Comment: Search SO for recursive hierarchical query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just did this because of StackOverflow user's understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not producing duplicate rows - it's returning the wrong data. Should be:

```
SELECT node.id, node.name 
FROM menu AS node, menu AS parent WHERE node.parentid = parent.id
```

BTW your data makes it really tricky to support deep/variable nesting from SQL (but I agree with Tim that the threading should be handled elsewhere). There are other ways to represent a hierarchy in a relational database.